# Examples of uses of descriptors in Python

Tags: python, descriptor

I hope this question isn't too open ended. After reading http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html, I finally "get" descriptors in Python.  But everything that I've seen on them just describes how they can be used to implement static methods, class methods, and properties.

I appreciate the importance of these, but what other kinds of uses are there for descriptors in Python? What kind of magic might I want my code to do that could only be implemented using descriptors (or at least best implemented using descriptors)?

Comment: I assume you also know that functions are descriptors and implement bound (and unbound, in Python 2) methods this way?

Comment: Right. To phrase it differently, I want to know what uses for descriptors there are other than those that are already built into the language.

Comment: It's a shame that your interesting question was closed within a day here.  A common use case is in the design of an ORM, e.g. Django uses [descriptors to implement the reverse relations](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9cfd060b1c0c3664d77e4ab30a6c351822f0a4d6/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L468) that you get for free on the related objects.

Comment: @wim unfortunately question closing is somewhat random on this site. I voted to reopen. I'm still curious about this mysterious feature of Python.

Comment: @asmeurer: The answers to this question would probably be better placed as examples in the new documentation feature anyway. The close reason is technically correct (there is no right answer to this quetion), but that doesn't mean the discussion is not valuable.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy-loaded properties:

```
import weakref
class lazyattribute(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.data = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
        self.f = f
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        if obj not in self.data:
            self.data[obj] = self.f(obj)
        return self.data[obj]
```

```
class Foo(object):
    @lazyattribute
    def bar(self):
        print "Doing a one-off expensive thing"
        return 42
```

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
Doing a one-off expensive thing
42
>>> f.bar
42
```

Comment: So basically caching.

Comment: @asmeurer: Essentially, yes